# Как вывести скопированные ячейки со второго столбца в третий? Сейчас выводится только первая, две других пустые

Tags: javascript, html

Код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to alert the innerHTML of the first cell (td element with index 0) in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Row3 cell1</td>
    <td >Row3 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var i = 0;
do {
  document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells.namedItem("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
  i++;
}
while (i < table.length);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

table.length равно undefined поетому, цикл проходит только 1ну итерацию

чутка подправил и заработало :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to alert the innerHTML of the first cell (td element with index 0) in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Row3 cell1</td>
    <td >Row3 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var i = 0;
do {
  document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells.namedItem("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;

  i++;
}
while (i <= table.childNodes.length);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Отлично!! Спасибо огромное работает! Работают оба варианта)

Comment: Незачто, но все же я бы предпочел вариант Sv__t, плюс цикл переписал бы на for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {}

Answer (score 0):

Имените `table.length` на `table.rows.length`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to alert the innerHTML of the first cell (td element with index 0) in the table's first row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Row3 cell1</td>
    <td >Row3 cell2</td>
    <td id="out"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var i = 0;
do {
  document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells.namedItem("out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
  i++;
}
while (i < table.rows.length);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```